# Where are the React Flow types defined?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

In the Flow documentation, the [React Type Reference](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/) article mentions various Flow types exported by the React module.

When digging into React's code, I cannot find any of those type definitions. Therefore, I do not understand how Flow can effectively parse them.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions can be viewed in [React type definitions](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.53.1/lib/react.js)

There is also a handy cheat sheet [here](https://www.saltycrane.com/flow-type-cheat-sheet/latest/) for quick reference.

Comment: Thank you! Yet the `import type {Node} from 'react'` is misleading. My wild guess is that flow somehow injects the React type definitions into the React library ? I have no clue on how my IDE will understand that...

Comment: Yeah, Flow will understand that. I've always used React.Node though, you have to import React if you use JSX anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some detailed discussion here:

https://medium.com/flow-type/even-better-support-for-react-in-flow-25b0a3485627

For React native you can do:

```
// @flow

import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

type Props = {
    style?: StyleSheet.Styles | Array<StyleSheet.Styles>
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this - Flow supports React types natively.
All react types are inside the Flow source code.